# Closing questions where the answerer has provided a MCVE

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

This question is related to a previous post of mine:

[Answering questions using own MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367154/answering-questions-using-own-mcve)

Should questions without a MCVE from the OP (still) be closed, when the answerer has provided a valid one in his/her response?

My view is that such questions should still be closed but I would welcome your input on this.

Comment: SO users have learned that posting a snippet is pretty important to get an answer.  They have not learned yet that it needs to be an MCVE, they often completely fail the M or the V.

Comment: If you have already commented on the question requesting one where it is required, and they do not post one, then yes. If you have not yet requested one via comments, then do that before voting to close.

Comment: @TylerH I always do that but most people do not bother. This is such an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734678/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the MCVE was *necessary* to solving the problem, i.e. the answer with the MCVE was a *guess*, then I'd close it. The MCVE being necessary to solving the problem means that we have no grounds for judging which answer is correct. I also don't like the idea of considering post-hoc evidence, such as the OP accepting the answer.

If the MCVE was *not* necessary--and there *are* plenty of debugging questions which can be answered without one--then for me it would depend on (1) how well-written the question is otherwise and (2) the long-term usefulness of the Q&A. It's pretty rare for a debugging question to be useful without an MCVE, though.

The thing to probably watch out for is the form of a typical canonical Q&A, which is like this:

> Q. I got a `FoobarCalledError`. What does it mean and why might it happen?
>
> A. It means you probably have some code like this:
>
> ```
> Foobar();
> ```
>
> You shouldn't call `Foobar`, because *x*, *y*, and *z*.

(See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2891664), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2891664), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2891664), etc.) New canonical Q&As usually happen when e.g. new language features are released, and we don't want to aimlessly close them.

Usually when we're talking about "missing an MCVE", though, we're talking about a question which asks about *how to fix a specific piece of code*. These are in general not very useful to anyone except the OP and maybe a few other people who happen to see the question when it's asked.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the exact situation.

Obviously an MCVE isn't needed for all question types, so lets assume this is a question that is about a piece of code that normally an MCVE would typically be needed.  Then it is depends on your definition of MCVE, as some users have a very strict definition of what the **C** and **V**.

Lack of an MCVE in the question isn't a requirement that means the question must be closed, but is a sign that the question may be unclear.  The key part of how to judge them is to think of the future people who will encounter the question.

- Is the problem an actual problem that other programmers will encounter and possibly need help with?
- Is the question phrased well enough that someone with the same problem will find the question via a search engine or via the internal search? (This assumes the quesiton is clear to begin with even without the MCVE),
- Is the title clear (for the same reasons)?
- Does the question have the right tags?
- Is the solution clear and does the MCVE in that answer help clearly address the problem?

In the end, the goal is to help users (not the OP but all users) solve their problems and if the question is clear and the answer is good, and the solution is understandable, then I don't see a reason to close the question just because there isn't a MCVE in the question.

Instead take the opportunity to edit the question so it is clearer, and make it easier to find.  Add the right tags, fix the title (if needed).  And maybe edit the MCVE into the question.  That way you can make it better for everyone.

Now if the question is vague and the answer is just guessing - then close away if you don't think you can salvage the question with editing.